# ElasticSearch read all unique values

Tags: elasticsearch

I know this question was asked several times here. But I need to know is it event possible to get **all** unique values of specific filed in ES.

What I came so far:

1. Request cardinality of a field:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "unique_count": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "fieldName"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Deduce number of partitions from cardinality: `total_partitions = unique_count / 10`.
3. Request terms for every partition **i**:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "value_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "fieldName",
                "include": {
                    "partition": $i,
                    "num_partitions": $total_partitions
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct? Or are there any other ways of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up with [elasticsearch-hadoop](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop). It contains Spark 
integration. We run Spark in local mode - the most simplest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I missed something in your question but a simple aggregation should give you all the unique value of a specific field with the corresponding count:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "unique_values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fieldName",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, when there are lots of unique terms, elasticsearch only returns the top terms. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html